# How to get href using beautiful soup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have a list of `<li>` each containing an `<a>` tag href url value and a `<span>` with its url title . I am trying to get the url by the span tag's title value. This is my example:

```
<li><a href="http://someurl"><span>Title of URL</span></a></li>
```

This is my last attempt:

```
soup.select_one('span:-soup-contains("Title of URL:")').find_previous_sibling(text=True)
```

But that won't work since the span is IN the `<a>` tag.
I've tried countless other variations that I have since deleted.

If anyone can help I'd be grateful.

Comment: Note that that `a` is not a sibling of your `span`, it's the parent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just select correct `<a>`:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_text = """\
<li><a href="http://someurl"><span>Title of URL</span></a></li>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text, "html.parser")

url = soup.select_one('a:-soup-contains("Title of URL")')["href"]
print(url)
```

Prints:

```
http://someurl
```